# btn-block with splited button dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The main idea:
Vertical buttons group list where each button fully fills parent by itself.

Problem:
split button dropdown don't do what I need. Adding `.btn-block` to button/button-group didn't resolve problem (dropdown moves to new line as separated button).

What I have:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
          Button 1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
         1
        </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
        Button 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
        Button 3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Problem:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
          Button 1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
         1
        </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
        Button 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
        Button 3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What need to do, to solve problem with splitted dropdown button? Like that:
[image]

Comment: Can't understand a thing. What exactly you wanna do, as the split buttons work correctly.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've added a screenshot with that whatI want see.

Comment: Gotcha... I got what you wanna do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding btn-block to the btn group. and also to the button itself. but it will move the menu opener to a new line. so I made a little trick you can see here:

```
jsfiddle.net/u753bbsg/
```